# What should I do when my local branch is at merging state after I pull the remote master?

Tags: github, merge

I am an Android developer, and now I am doing a lot of changes locally and are trying to synchronize the local and github side of the code after I pull the merge to merge successfully and merge the code locally and run successfully.

But when I want to push always show the picture shown in the picture, push rejected. I am very puzzled, the left side of the figure is the local change, since I was a novice, no previous to ignore the file, so a series of build files, `.idea` files have been submitted to see the error is to show that these files are not merged.

Now I am very puzzled, how can I solve this situation, how can I submit the local code to my github library, who can help me? Many thanks!

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have commits in the **remote** version of `master` that you're pushing to that are not in your local version, and vice versa. Since Git can't resolve this diversion automatically, you can't push your local version to your remote.

You may have to [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), or if that doesn't work, [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), to get your branches to line up in a way that they can be merged.

Comment: Now the situation is that I have pulled it once and have put my github library code into the local, so my local code is already my local change plus github library code, but because some useless files .build , .idea, not all merged, but in the merging state, it can not push, I really do not know how to do